# Is it common tradeoff to consider, that interaction between Bounded Contexts may "cripple Open Closed Principle"?

Tags: oop, events, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I am implementing interaction between bounded contexts and I found out that it "somehow" cripples open closed principle and I am not sure, whether it is natural consequence of designing BCs and common tradeoff to consider or my design failure.

Consider Shop BC where you can create Order out of Cart with some items. Created order consists of `OrderItem`s, each of them containing one of various types of `ItemSpecification` Value Object Interface like `ProductSpecification` or `FooServiceSpecification`, protecting invariants and containing some data. When Order is created, asynchronous event that can be listened to by any other BC is emitted.

That asynchronous event is created out of Order and is represented as (serialized) OrderCreatedEvent object, containing OrderDTO object, all placed in Core namespace which is shared with every BC so that any BC can depend on Core, but not the other way. All good so far, almost:

That OrderItemDTO must contain interface `ItemSpecificationDTO`, which need be implemented for every type of specification. My `ItemSpecification` VO (like any other VO/Entity in Order) has `toCoreDTO()` method to pragmatically achieve easy translation and it also makes relatively hard to implement new `ItemSpecification` and forget to implement according DTO. That's probably okay.

But what about other BC's which listen to that Event? In every BC this Event needs to be translated in it's AntiCorruption Layer and that BC may be interested only in some types of `ItemSpecificationDTO` and translate them to various Value Objects, important for that specific BC.

As Uncle Bob says about OCP in a wit:

> You should be able to extend the behavior of a system without having
>   to modify that system.

But when I implement new type of `ItemSpecification`, for every BC which may be interested in this new type I need to specifically translate that new type from CoreDTO (okay I could write some abstraction for translating in each BC so I would still be just adding code without modyfying anything like adding if($x instanceof X)). But still, by adding new type of `ItemSpecification` I need to make appropriate extensions (and maybe even modify something because we don't live in ideal world) in other BCs.

And I do not know how to think about that. Is that downside of whole DDD approach? Or maybe feature indeed, because that hunting for what, where and how needs to be further extended in other BCs, is driven by domain needs instead of technical concerns? It seems right. In the end, I'm trying to do domain driven design :-) But it seems to me somehow dangerous too. I am afraid that one day we can forget to update some other BC and something bad happens. But that is probably because I play big part of domain expert role too, under which that "fear" should probably belong. Is my problem just sitting on two chairs or did I got something wrong? :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of interesting details about this topic, but I would concentrate here on one specific aspect of bounded contexts.

That is that they are bounded for a reason. As in, there should be a boundary between the models/understanding of these contexts. Two contexts, even if they are related should have a different view on the system, even on the data that might be partly shared.

It seems to me that your "bounded contexts" want to work on the same model. You even created a "core" model which everyone can see and apparently must be able to understand. If this is the case, I'd argue that you lost the benefits of having different contexts, and you are just creating one big application, with one model.

To correct this problem, I think you would need to get rid of any central/core models, and work with "local" (bounded) models in the different contexts/services. When you need to communicate with other components, you need to define a protocol for those two, dictated by either or both parties.

For example a Shopping Cart might need to know the product-id for the backend system to create the order there. But the backend system doesn't need to know the model the shopping cart uses to know what the order is about (in its own model).

Comment: I dont think so, because in that Core, i have just and only 1) DTOs for asynchronous events that are emitted to communicate between bounded contexts. Also, In each BC listening for any of that event is AntiCorruption layer, translating that Core Event DTO to it's domain specific VOs - no leaking one BC into another then. 2) Identities - Value objects like UserId containing uuid and 3) some useful abstraction that is not domain specific (something like AbstractCommandbus would go there)... Do you?

Comment: Obviously I don't know your specific case in detail, but: 1. Communications and protocols are difficult. It requires both (or multiple) parties to agree. It should be something non-changing, or very rarely changing. It also should be backwards compatible each time. This is no place to define domain-specific entities in detail. 3. Non-domain specific things should be in libraries, maybe open-source on github, like what netflix does.

Comment: Also, an anti-corruption layer is supposed to solve problems with legacy-systems that can't really adapt. If you control both sides anyway (it seem you do) then I would see no reason to have an additional layer. So again, this is just my opinion, but I would try to get these systems separated more thoroughly.

Comment: But I am not specifying any entity in Core, there is just DTO that is just specification of bunch of data that need to be in OrderCreated Event, same as if you would serialize it in json. About that non domain specific things you are right. And about anti corruption layer, well if I would use event as serialized array of data instead of using Core DTOs, I would need to map those array data into some DTO or maybe VO that are specific for BC that listens to that event. Not using AC and translation wouls not be possible with serialized arrays, but I could use those CoreDTO without translation.

Comment: About no entities in the Core: I understand you specify these things just for the sake of the protocol. However your original problem seems to be that "ItemSpecifications" need to be extended, and that (as I understand) somehow need to be represented in the protocol too. I suggest that that might be because someone's (some context's) domain is seeping into the global protocol. The protocol should be fixed. I contend that the order system only needs to know the product id, it does not need to know the complete structure of a product.

Comment: Not at all, I do not want just asynchronous notification, but event carried state as Martin Fowler talks about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0 - other BCs of course will be interested in informations about order that was created to perform action. If I send just event notification with ID, listening BC's will need to ask for more information and I will need to create and keep many protocols for each listening BC that needs to ask more than just ID. And in the end, I will be forced to extend some of them along with extending `ItemSpecifications` also, anyway.

Comment: That is why I came to conclusion that maybe this "crippling OCP" comes from domain that needs to update one BC because another BC was updated. But, I don't need to update that BC or extend any Core DTO _technically_ - everything should still work as it was.